# Como passar valores para um array depois de clicar em submit

Tags: php, html, array, objetos

Estou trabalhando com a documentação do mercado pago, onde tenho uma nova instancia/objeto para cada produto chamado item. Cada item tem que ser passado para a instância de preference->items onde o método preference->save(), irá salvar e enviar um POST quando eu clicar no botão pagar do ML. O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte

- Tenho um form com 3 inputs do tipo submit.
- Cada input tem uma propriedade hidden e um value que corresponde ao valor do produto
- Quando o usuário clicar em submit, que seria o mesmo que adicionar ao carrinho, quero pegar a instancia/objeto chamado item e passar dentro do array de preference->items.

A forma que estou tentando é a seguinte:

```
<?php 
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

// Cria um item na preferência
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = 'Produto 1';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = 23.00;



$item2 = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item2->title = 'Produto 2';
$item2->quantity = 1;
$item2->unit_price = 10.00;



$item3 = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item3->title = 'Produto 3';
$item3->quantity = 1;
$item3->unit_price = 1.99;
openssl_get_cert_locations();


if (isset($_POST['produto1'])) {
    $preference->items = array($item);
    $preference->save();
}
if (isset($_POST['produto2'])) {
    $preference->items = array($item2);
    $preference->save();
}
if (isset($_POST['produto3'])) {
    $preference->items = array($item3);
    $preference->save();
}

?>
```

Como é necessário fazer o uso de algum certificando SSL estou executando esta página em um host gratuito, no caso este link: https://max360vision.000webhostapp.com/playground.php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p> Produto: <input type="text" name="produto1" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

    <p> Produto 2: <input type="text" name="produto2" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit2">

    <p> Produto 3: <input type="text" name="produto3" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit3">

</form>
<form action="/processar_pagamento" method="POST">
    <script src="https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js" data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
    </script>
</form>
```

O erro que me ocorre da forma que estou tentando atualmente é o seguinte: Toda vez que eu dou submit em qualquer produto, ele manda 2 avisos da classe manager que ja vem com o SDK do mercado

> livre Notice: Undefined index: metadata in
>   /storage/ssd3/656/11276656/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Manager.php
>   on line 336
>
> Notice: Undefined index: metadata in
>   /storage/ssd3/656/11276656/public_html/vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Manager.php
>   on line 336

E quando clico pagar ele redireciona para pagar o item 3, mesmo que eu clique no item 1, ou 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, não entendi o motivo, mas depois de escrever o código e tentar testar pedaço por pedaço consegui. Pelo que eu observei a lógica esta correta, porém quando dou submit em form, há um submit no formulário de todos os outros botões como se eu tivesse clicado nos 3 outros botões, após separa-los em 3 forms diferentes, deu certo, o resultado ficou desta forma:

```html
if (!isset($_POST['produto1'])) {
    $preference->items = array();
}else{
    
   $preference->items = array($item);
   $preference->save();
   var_dump($preference->items);
 }

if (!isset($_POST['produto2'])) {
     $preference->items = array();
}else{
    
   $preference->items = array($item2);
   $preference->save();
   var_dump($preference->items);
} 



if (!isset($_POST['produto3'])) {
     $preference->items = array();
}else{
   $preference->items = array($item3);
   $preference->save();
   var_dump($preference->items);
    
 }


?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <p> Produto: <input type="text" name="produto1" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p> Produto 2: <input type="text" name="produto2" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit2">
</form>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <p> Produto 3: <input type="text" name="produto3" hidden></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="submit3">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> Produto 1: <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value='1' ></p>
<p> Produto 2: <input type="hidden" name="produto[]  value='2'></p>
<p> Produto 3: <input type="hidden" name="produto[]" value='3'></p>
```